# Navigation from a HTML file into another

Tags: html

I have 2 html files in my desktop(login.html & firstpage.html). I have a button in login.html. when i pressed that button i need to navigate to firstpage.html screen.

I have tried like below; I wrote this in login.html page, But it's not working,

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="Enter" width="100px" onclick="<a href ='C:\Users\Desktop\firstpage.html'</a>">
</form>
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.Thanks

Comment: The HTML code is not showing ;) if you could edit your question

Comment: To make code readable on SO, you can indent it 4 spaces, or click the code button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in

```
<form name="myform" action="firstpage.html">
<input type="submit" value="Enter" width="100px">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To just link the two files, all you need is to have them in the same folder, and use this line:

```
<input type="button" value="Enter" width="100px" onclick="document.location='firstpage.html'">
```

You do not need a form to do this.

Your onclick handler does not need html in it, just the javascript.

You could also do:

```
<a href="firstpage.html">Go to page</a>
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: firstpage is not defined` — The `onclick` attribute contains *JavaScript* not a URL.

Comment: ha! So right!   you need javscript to do this if your not using a link.

Answer (score 0):

Make Slight changes in your code like this

```
<a href ='C:\Users\documents\firstpage.html'><input type="button" value="Enter" width="100px"></input></a>
```

This should work... :)